# How to compare two different data frames in pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, compare

The data frames are not similar in any way. They do not have the same values. I want to be able to compare one column from one df with another column from the other and graph them.  For example, one df has a column named "Offical poverty total" and another df has a column named "violent crime rate".  I want to be able to compare these two.

I tried df['Offical Poverty_Total'].append(crime['Violent crime'])
but this isn't what I was looking for. To make it simple, I want to have a new table with the two columns and be able to analyze the new table.

Comment: what do you mean by compare? "compare" can mean many different things.

Comment: ok. To make it simple, I want to make a new table with a column from one df and another column from the other df.

Comment: Does `df['Violent crime'] = crime['Violent crime']` not do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for

```
pd.concat((df['Offical Poverty_Total'], crime['Violent crime']), axis = 1)
```

This will align their indexes, so if you've changed the row ordering of the dataframes and want to just glue them together in the order you see them in, do

```
pd.concat((df['Offical Poverty_Total'], crime['Violent crime']), axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: ok thanks! When i try this it says "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" . Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I restarted the kernel in pandas and it worked perfectly. Not sure why the error came up at first but thank you so much!